# Is Hibernate using pessimistic or optimistic locking?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, transactions, locking

All my classes have an

@Version

annotation, so I assumed they were using optimistic locking.

But I the following exception in my logs that seem to indicate Im using pessimistic locking. So which is it ? (I want to use optimistic locking)

```
update Song set acoustidFingerprint=?, acoustidId=?, album=?, albumArtist=?, albumArtistSort=?, albumSort=?, amazonId=?, arranger=?, artist=?, artistSort=?, artists=?, barcode=?, bpm=?, catalogNo=?, comment=?, composer=?, composerSort=?, conductor=?, country=?, custom1=?, custom2=?, custom3=?, custom4=?, custom5=?, discNo=?, discSubtitle=?, discTotal=?, djmixer=?, duration=?, encoder=?, engineer=?, fbpm=?, filename=?, genre=?, grouping=?, isCompilation=?, isrc=?, keyOfSong=?, language=?, lastModified=?, lyricist=?, lyrics=?, media=?, mixer=?, mood=?, musicbrainzArtistId=?, musicbrainzDiscId=?, musicbrainzOriginalReleaseId=?, musicbrainzRecordingId=?, musicbrainzReleaseArtistId=?, musicbrainzReleaseCountry=?, musicbrainzReleaseGroupId=?, musicbrainzReleaseId=?, musicbrainzReleaseStatus=?, musicbrainzReleaseType=?, musicbrainzWorkId=?, musicipId=?, occasion=?, originalAlbum=?, originalArtist=?, originalLyricist=?, originalYear=?, producer=?, quality=?, rating=?, recordLabel=?, releaseYear=?, remixer=?, script=?, subtitle=?, tags=?, tempo=?, title=?, titleSort=?, track=?, trackTotal=?, urlDiscogsArtistSite=?, urlDiscogsReleaseSite=?, urlLyricsSite=?, urlOfficialArtistSite=?, urlOfficialReleaseSite=?, urlWikipediaArtistSite=?, urlWikipediaReleaseSite=?, version=? where recNo=? and version=? [50200-172]
**org.hibernate.PessimisticLockException: Timeout trying to lock table ; SQL statement:**
update Song set acoustidFingerprint=?, acoustidId=?, album=?, albumArtist=?, albumArtistSort=?, albumSort=?, amazonId=?, arranger=?, artist=?, artistSort=?, artists=?, barcode=?, bpm=?, catalogNo=?, comment=?, composer=?, composerSort=?, conductor=?, country=?, custom1=?, custom2=?, custom3=?, custom4=?, custom5=?, discNo=?, discSubtitle=?, discTotal=?, djmixer=?, duration=?, encoder=?, engineer=?, fbpm=?, filename=?, genre=?, grouping=?, isCompilation=?, isrc=?, keyOfSong=?, language=?, lastModified=?, lyricist=?, lyrics=?, media=?, mixer=?, mood=?, musicbrainzArtistId=?, musicbrainzDiscId=?, musicbrainzOriginalReleaseId=?, musicbrainzRecordingId=?, musicbrainzReleaseArtistId=?, musicbrainzReleaseCountry=?, musicbrainzReleaseGroupId=?, musicbrainzReleaseId=?, musicbrainzReleaseStatus=?, musicbrainzReleaseType=?, musicbrainzWorkId=?, musicipId=?, occasion=?, originalAlbum=?, originalArtist=?, originalLyricist=?, originalYear=?, producer=?, quality=?, rating=?, recordLabel=?, releaseYear=?, remixer=?, script=?, subtitle=?, tags=?, tempo=?, title=?, titleSort=?, track=?, trackTotal=?, urlDiscogsArtistSite=?, urlDiscogsReleaseSite=?, urlLyricsSite=?, urlOfficialArtistSite=?, urlOfficialReleaseSite=?, urlWikipediaArtistSite=?, urlWikipediaReleaseSite=?, version=? where recNo=? and version=? [50200-172]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect$2.convert(H2Dialect.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3123)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3021)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3350)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1182)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1611)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
    at com.jthink.songkong.db.SongCache.loadSongsFromDatabase(SongCache.java:58)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.SongGroup.getSongs(SongGroup.java:48)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MergeMusicBrainzMatches.matchToMissingTracks(MergeMusicBrainzMatches.java:318)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MergeMusicBrainzMatches.call(MergeMusicBrainzMatches.java:105)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MergeMusicBrainzMatches.call(MergeMusicBrainzMatches.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Timeout trying to lock table ; SQL statement:
update Song set acoustidFingerprint=?, acoustidId=?, album=?, albumArtist=?, albumArtistSort=?, albumSort=?, amazonId=?, arranger=?, artist=?, artistSort=?, artists=?, barcode=?, bpm=?, catalogNo=?, comment=?, composer=?, composerSort=?, conductor=?, country=?, custom1=?, custom2=?, custom3=?, custom4=?, custom5=?, discNo=?, discSubtitle=?, discTotal=?, djmixer=?, duration=?, encoder=?, engineer=?, fbpm=?, filename=?, genre=?, grouping=?, isCompilation=?, isrc=?, keyOfSong=?, language=?, lastModified=?, lyricist=?, lyrics=?, media=?, mixer=?, mood=?, musicbrainzArtistId=?, musicbrainzDiscId=?, musicbrainzOriginalReleaseId=?, musicbrainzRecordingId=?, musicbrainzReleaseArtistId=?, musicbrainzReleaseCountry=?, musicbrainzReleaseGroupId=?, musicbrainzReleaseId=?, musicbrainzReleaseStatus=?, musicbrainzReleaseType=?, musicbrainzWorkId=?, musicipId=?, occasion=?, originalAlbum=?, originalArtist=?, originalLyricist=?, originalYear=?, producer=?, quality=?, rating=?, recordLabel=?, releaseYear=?, remixer=?, script=?, subtitle=?, tags=?, tempo=?, title=?, titleSort=?, track=?, trackTotal=?, urlDiscogsArtistSite=?, urlDiscogsReleaseSite=?, urlLyricsSite=?, urlOfficialArtistSite=?, urlOfficialReleaseSite=?, urlWikipediaArtistSite=?, urlWikipediaReleaseSite=?, version=? where recNo=? and version=? [50200-172]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:158)
    at org.h2.command.Command.filterConcurrentUpdate(Command.java:281)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:237)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:154)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:140)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using optimistic locking, as your `UPDATE` statement already indicates:

```
where recNo=? and version=?
```

The presence of the `version` column is what optimistic locking is all about.

You were misled by the `PessimisticLockException` which might be caused by an explicit or an implicit row-level lock.

Answer (score 17):

This exception is due to Lock TimeOut.

*Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Timeout trying to lock table ;*

Check a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162557/timeout-error-trying-to-lock-table-in-h2)

Also hibernate provides mechanisms for implementing both types of locking in your applications.

Your locking strategy can be either optimistic or pessimistic.

**Optimistic**

Optimistic locking assumes that multiple transactions can complete without affecting each other, and that therefore transactions can proceed without locking the data resources that they affect. Before committing, each transaction verifies that no other transaction has modified its data. If the check reveals conflicting modifications, the committing transaction rolls back[1].

**Pessimistic**

Pessimistic locking assumes that concurrent transactions will conflict with each other, and requires resources to be locked after they are read and only unlocked after the application has finished using the data.

Details can be found [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html)

Comment: Thanks I'll  try out the h2 MVCC parameter, But your answer doesn't address my primary concern which it to put it another way 'Why does hibernate appear to be using pessemistic locking when I believe i have it configured to use optimistic locking ?'

Comment: Update, just discovered Im already using MVCC or at least trying to by connection url is jdbc:h2:songkong/database;FILE_LOCK=SOCKET;MVCC=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE

Comment: Also please try to append ;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000 i.e. 10 seconds as the default timeout is very low i.e. 1 second or 1000 ms

Comment: Also org.hibernate.PessimisticLockException shows that your application is using Pessimistic Locking. This exception is thrown when a pessimistic locking conflict occurs.

Comment: So why is is using pessemistic locking when my classes are annotated with the @Version annotation (for optimistic locking)

Comment: Resources here means the entire table or just the rows?

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely, that you will use a different database for Testing, than you do in LIVE environment.

H2 can produce errors, which might not appear on LIVE Database like Oracle, MySQL a.s.o.. Means even your code is correct, but the H2 can possibly be messing around.

The MVCC=true works perfectly. 
At the same time you should ensure that you have full integration tests on LIVE like systems for your use case in order to verify the LIVE Database behaviour.