# JUnit + DBUnit DBUnitTester causes lock?

Tags: java, sql, junit, h2, dbunit

I insert in a H2 in memory DataBase some testdata with dbunit, make an update and want to delete the testdata from the db after the test has run.

My JUnit @Before setup

```
databaseTester.setSetUpOperation(DatabaseOperation.INSERT);
databaseTester.setDataSet(testDataSet);
databaseTester.onSetup();
```

In a JUnit test method i got something like this

```
String sql = "UPDATE table SET column='valuenew' WHERE column='valueold'"
SQLQuery query = sessionHandler.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.executeUpdate();
```

My JUnit @After teardown

```
databaseTester.setDataSet(testDataSet);
DatabaseOperation tearDownOperation = DatabaseOperation.DELETE;
databaseTester.setTearDownOperation(tearDownOperation);
databaseTester.onTearDown();
```

I am not even sure if the update gets executed but the first exception i get is when onTearDown is called.

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: ZeitÃ¼berschreitung beim Versuch die Tabelle "DT405" zu    sperren
Timeout trying to lock table "table"; SQL statement:
delete from PUBLIC.table where column = ? [50200-175]
```

Seems like there is a lock already on the table. Select queries work fine but update statements fail.

Any hints what is going wrong?

Related:
[Timeout error trying to lock table in h2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162557/timeout-error-trying-to-lock-table-in-h2)

Update:
MVCC=true didn't fix the problem, i test now if a pending transaction causes the lock

Comment: did you check this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162557/timeout-error-trying-to-lock-table-in-h2

Comment: seems like it is the same reason.

Comment: You have a pending transaction (the update) and need to either `commit` or `rollback` to release the transaction.

Comment: I will try this, i have only one connection but atm i dont coommit explicitly, i am not sure if dbunit dbtester does it