# Getting JdbcBatchUpdateException while testing with EmbeddedDatabase H2

Tags: java, sql, spring, h2

I get strange exception trying to test my code using EmbeddedDatabase H2:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: Timeout trying to lock table "CO_SCENARIO_1"; SQL statement:
UPDATE CO_SCENARIO_1 SET VALUE = ? WHERE ATTRIBUTE = ? AND MODIFIER = ? [50200-156]
    at de.telekom.skses.test.dao.DatabaseFileConverterTest.fromFile(DatabaseFileConverterTest.java:99)
```

This is part of code I'm trying to test:

```
case "overriddenVariables.txt": {
                        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(bOut.toString())) {
                            try (Connection con = dataSource.getConnection()) {
                                String aQuery = "UPDATE $tableName SET VALUE = ? WHERE ATTRIBUTE = ? AND MODIFIER = ?";
                                String line = "";
                                if (sc.hasNext()) {
                                    line = sc.nextLine();
                                }
                                while (sc.hasNext()) {
                                    if (line.startsWith("+")) {
                                        String setting = line.substring(1);
                                        try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(aQuery.replace("$tableName", setting))) {

                                            while (sc.hasNext() && !(line = sc.nextLine()).startsWith("+")) {
                                                int del1 = line.indexOf(":");
                                                int del2 = line.indexOf(':', del1 + 1);
                                                String attr = line.substring(0, del1);
                                                String modifier = line.substring(del1 + 1, del2);
                                                String value = line.substring(del2 + 1, line.length());
                                                Clob myClob = con.createClob();
                                                myClob.setString(1, value);
                                                ps.setClob(1, myClob);
                                                ps.setString(2, attr);
                                                ps.setString(3, modifier);
                                                ps.addBatch();
                                            }
                                            ps.executeBatch();
                                        }

                                    }
                                }

                            } catch (SQLException e) {
                                logger.error("Error", e);
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            logger.error("Error", ex);
                            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                        }

                        break;
                    }
```

StackOverflow says that I should set lock timeout, but I didn't find how to set it for EmbeddedDatabase. Also, in previous version I opened new PreparedStatement for each query and new Connection for each PreparedStatement, everything worked well, and I can't understand why it doesn't now. Could you please explain what I have to do to make it work again?

Sorry if something is incorrect, I'm new to Java EE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I remember using H2 in embedded mode, it has problems with concurrency. this is probably why you get the timeout for the lock on the table, since the table is still updated from your last batch when you try to execute the next one. When closing connection and preparedStatement every single time the execution time is way shorter, so you won't get the timeout.

Have you tried adding to the DatabaseURL `;MVCC=true` as stated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162557/timeout-error-trying-to-lock-table-in-h2)? If this won't solve the problem, is it really necessary to use batches for your update?

EDIT: the post i linked before, links to the [h2 website](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_lock_timeout) where you can find a description on how to change the lock timeout by adding `;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000` to your databse URL. This would change it to 10 seconds, standard is 1 second

Comment: Sorry, but how can I add this settings to EmbeddedDatabase? I just autowire dataSource created like `@Bean 
public EmbeddedDatabase dataSource() { return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2) ... .build() }`

Comment: Ok i just googled a lot about it, but if you're not using any spring.config files where you specify the URL i don't know if this is possible. Only way i can think of where you maybe trick it into doing what you want could be using the `.setName("testDB;MVCC=true")`method. since as stated [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-embedded-database-examples/) spring creates the DB with `jdbc:h2:mem:testDb` as URL, so maybe by calling the DB `testDB;MVCC=true` it will work

Comment: you could name it anyway you want it by the way, I simply used "testDb" ;)