# H2 lock timeout quicker than the defined timeout, why?

Tags: java, timeout, h2

We are using a H2 DB, embedded mode, db file on disk, version h2-1.3.176.jar. When we started to run a few 10 threads in parallel using the database we quickly started getting

```
 org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Timeout trying to lock table ...
```

By following https://stackoverflow.com/a/4162685/2954288 to set the lock timeout (we use `SET DEFAULT_LOCK_TIMEOUT`) the situation improved only slightly.

The really confusing thing is that we get timeouts shortly after starting up the Java process, long before the first time would expire, e.g. 3 seconds after startup we get a timeout despite the timeout being 10 seconds.

Is there some queue that spills over and that we need to configure too or something else we must configure?

(We would rather not use MVCC=true, since it is marked as experimental and not fully tested)

Comment: Might be a corrupted database, try recreating with `SCRIPT` `RUNSCRIPT`. You are also using a very old version, consider upgrading to the latest or to the latest stable.